# How do I make my .exe available for "Open With" in Windows?

Tags: windows

I'm writing an application in C/C++/Cuda C in Visual Studio 2019, and it compiles into an executable application.

I was wondering if anyone knew how to make Windows acknowledge this application as one for which is an option when the user right clicks on a certain type of file and clicks on "Open With". Essentially, I want my application to be there. Does anyone know how this is done, or why an application shows up there to begin with?

I will note that I do deploy my application with a Windows Installer (.msi and setup.exe files) and that accompanying project in Visual Studio.

Thank you.

Comment: You mean you want the executable to be associated with a data file having your unique `.xtn` ? "Open with" allows you to set that association - *always* open with this. Then you can double-click the data file to run the app.

Comment: @WeatherVane sure! Ok, so how would I go about getting windows to give my app as an option in that initial "Open With" section without having to click the "See more options" tab?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration#registering-verbs-and-other-file-association-information

Comment: After "open with" if it is not an installed program, you can browse to find the executable.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant !